# using macdeployqt with arm64 build

Tags: macos, qt, arm64, apple-silicon, macdeployqt

I have problems using `macdeployqt` with arm64 build. I am on Apple Silicon M1 machine with macOS12 (Monterey). I have installed Qt 6.2.1 and XCode 13.1.

I created a very simple console application.

```
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << "Hello world.";
}
```

with qmake PRO file:

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I call `qmake` with `QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS="arm64"`. It successfully creates app bundle.

Then I try to run `macdeployqt` from Qt 6.2.1 bin directory:

```
./macdeployqt /Users/vk/build-ConsoleApp-Qt_6_2_1_for_macOS_XCode-Release/ConsoleApp.app
```

...and I receive lots of messages:

```
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "/Users/vk/Qt/6.2.1/macos/lib/QtSvg.framework/Versions/A/QtSvg (architecture arm64):"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "/Users/vk/Qt/6.2.1/macos/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/A/QtWidgets (architecture arm64):"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "/Users/vk/Qt/6.2.1/macos/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/A/QtGui (architecture arm64):"
ERROR: Could not parse otool output line: "/Users/vk/Qt/6.2.1/macos/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/A/QtNetwork (architecture arm64):"
...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like it chokes on fat binaries. If you can change the otool invocation, then adding `-arch arm64` might help.

Comment: @Siguza do you happen to know how to do this? From what I understood I can't add any arguments to otool since I don't invoke it directly (macdeployqt invokes otool)

Comment: UPDATE: apparently those "errors" can be ignored. macdeployqt just gets confused about ARM architecture. Cheers! =)

Comment: The errors have been changed to warnings as mentioned on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98466